# Do my companions give me something back when I give them equipment?

Tags: the-last-remnant

Companions will often ask for a nice piece of equipment. If I give them one, will I get whatever they are replacing back? I don't mind giving them the nice stuff, but I'd like to know if it'll end up in the trash when they ask for even nicer stuff.

Comment: I absolutely hated the companion equipment mechanic in that game.  Sometimes its a pain in the ass just to get them to ask for something you know they need but they refuse to ask for it.

Comment: @spartacus yeah, I can see what they were trying to do - inventory management on a 50 person party would be a nightmare, but they seem to have created something even worse.